# Caratheodory Extension Theorem- Is the measure defined on algebra $\Sigma_0$, defined in the same way as the extension to $\Sigma=\sigma(\Sigma_0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Sorry if the title is not clear. I'm using David Williams book "Probability with Martingales" Chapter $1$, Theorem $1.7$ In it he states the Caratheodory Extension Theorem by:

> Let $S$ be a set, let $\Sigma_0$ be an algebra on $S$, and let $$\Sigma:=\sigma(\Sigma_0).$$
>   If $\mu_0$ is a countably additive map $\mu_0:\Sigma_0\rightarrow [0,\infty]$, then there exists a measure $\mu$ on $(S,\Sigma)$ such that $$\mu=\mu_0\;\text{on}\; \Sigma_0.$$
>   If $\mu_0(S)<\infty$, then this extension is unique.

My question is whether $\mu$ (on $\Sigma$) is consistent with the way $\mu_0$ is defined on $\Sigma_0$ or does it just happen that they coincide on $\Sigma_0$? I believe this has to do with the last statement of uniqueness... i.e. if unique then clearly the countable additive map $\mu_0$ ($=\mu$) on $\Sigma_0$ is the only measure possible which extends $\Sigma_0$ to $\Sigma$?

Comment: I do not really understand what's unclear to you. If $\mu_0$ has certain properties (countably additive) then it can be extended. If it has an extra property ($\mu_0(S)<\infty$) then this extension is unique. Definition of $\mu_0$ and $\mu$ are no part of the game here.

Comment: When $\mu_0$ is extended to $\Sigma$ is the extension necessarily the same map? Or is this just stating that such a map (measure) exists on $\Sigma$ that coincides with $\mu_0$ on $\Sigma_0$?

Comment: The statement "$\mu_0$ defined on $\Sigma_0$ can be extended to a measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$" is actually the same as "there exists a measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ such that the restriction of $\mu$ to $\Sigma_0$ coincides with $\mu_0$". In mathematical notation $\mu\upharpoonleft\Sigma_{0}=\mu_{0}$. The extension is not fully the same map since it has a larger domain. But that's all. On the original domain the extension coincides with the map.